# No hostname/Tag passed from TD Agent to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to send events from TD agent to ElasticSearch and Kibana but it is not working

My Td agent conf:

```
  <source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/abc.log
  pos_file /etc/td-agent/def.pos
  refresh_interval 10s
  tag "abc.def"
  format /^(?<Time>[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<Logging_Level>\[(.*)\]) (?<PID>\  [(.*)\]) \[\-\:\-\] (?<Message>(.*))$/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
 </source>

 <filter "abc.def">
 type record_transformer
  <record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
  </record>
 </filter>

 <match "abc.def">
 type elasticsearch
 logstash_format true
  host xyz.def.domain
  port 9200 #(optional; default=9200)
  flush_interval 10s
  index_name logstash #(optional; default=fluentd)
   </match>
```

Not sure why it is not sending hostname from TD agent to ElasticSearch and Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable ruby in record_transformer, this is ruby expression:

```
"#{Socket.gethostname}"
```

So it should look like this:

```
 <filter "abc.def">
 type record_transformer
 enable_ruby true 
 <record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
  </record>
 </filter>
```